# Unable to add a contact using Bronto services

Tags: python-3.x, soap, suds, bronto

I am trying to add a contact using the Bronto SOAP services. I am using the suds library in python3.
Here's the code:

```
import sys
import datetime
BRONTO_WSDL = 'https://api.bronto.com/v4?wsdl'
TOKEN = "My Token Id"
from suds.client import Client
from suds import WebFault
bApi = Client( BRONTO_WSDL )
session_id = bApi.service.login(TOKEN) #sends a request, returns 200
session_header = bApi.factory.create("sessionHeader")
session_header.sessionId = session_id
bApi.set_options(soapheaders=session_header)
contact = bApi.factory.create('contactObject')
contact.email = "An email id"
contact_result = bApi.service.addOrUpdateContacts(contact) #sends a request, returns 500 !
```

It returns an error message which says

```
Server raised fault: '104: You do not have valid access for this method.'
```

I am not able to figure out the issue here. Can anyone help me out here?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The token you're using does not have write permissions, hence the error. To fix the issue, login to http://www.bronto.com, goto **Home->Settings->Data Exchange**, locate the token you're using, click on "*Edit Settings*", then check the "*Write*" checkbox.

[image: screenshot of "Edit Settings" popup]

Source: http://dev.bronto.com/gettingstarted/soap-how-to-get-started/how-to-access-the-api/